# C# GetCustomattributes from class name

Tags: c#, custom-attributes, getcustomattributes

Is it possible to get the custom attributes from the class name as a string?

something like this (which doesn't work)

```
Type myType = Type.GetType("MyClass");
MemberInfo info = myType // typeof(myType);
object[] atts = info.GetCustomAttributes(true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. You missed namespace.

```
 Type myType = Type.GetType("System.String");
 object[] atts = myType.GetCustomAttributes(true);
```

In your case

```
Type myType = Type.GetType("YourNameSpace.MyClass");//this should work
```

Refer [Type.GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) for more info

```
var asnames = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies();
var asmname = asnames.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == assemName);
Assembly.Load(asmname);
```

Use the above code to preload the assembly(If it exists in your referenced assembly)

Comment: Type myType = Type.GetType("YourNameSpace.MyClass"); returns null for me. Is there a way to get this for referenced assemblies - possibly that have not been used, so may not be loaded (if .NET does lazy load?)

Comment: @user2707101 Am afraid, It is possible but why do you need to pre load the assembly?

Comment: This works:  String strFile = assemName + ".dll";
        Byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(dllPath + strFile);
        Assembly assem = Assembly.Load(bytes);
        Type typeDefinition = assem.GetType(assemName + ".Entity." + entityName);  But there must be an easier way to get the Type?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're almost there.

Use  `object[] atts = Type.GetType("MyNamesapce.MyClass").GetCustomAttributes(true);`

Worked flawlessly for me

Perhaps you missed mentioning the namespace?.

Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute.getcustomattributes.aspx

Comment: Thanks this works with "System.String" but not with "Mynamespace.myclass" - which is in a separate dll, but referenced and has a using statement so should be available.  Maybe I have to do something with GetAssembly.